# kIOHIDOptionsTypeSeizeDevice causes device to become unresponsive

Tags: macos, hid, iokit

I'm trying to write a simple command line program which sends keystrokes on a given keyboard to a UDP server. I'm programming on OSX using the `IOKit` framework and its `IOHIDManager` class.

For the purpose of my program, I'd like to use the `kIOHIDOptionsTypeSeizeDevice` when opening the `IOHIDManager` instance and sending the UDP messages in the callback setup using `IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback`.

When I setup the filtering through the `IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching` function to match the internal keyboard of my MacBook Pro, everything works fine: key presses aren't passed on to the focused application anymore and events correctly sent over UDP.

When I try to match a USB CardReader ( http://www.gitak.com/GIT-200USB.PDF ), everything works correctly up to the first event sent by the device when swiping a card. After the first character, the registered callback isn't called anymore.

To be more precise:

- Device is correctly matched (even if unplugged multiple times)
- First received character is correctly handled
- The device has a LED to indicate when it's ready for a new swipe, normally after a swipe it turns back green, but in this case, after the first event is sent, it remains off
- Everything works as expected when using the internal keyboard with `kIOHIDOptionsTypeSeizeDevice`
- Everything works as expected when using the card reader with `kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone` instead of `kIOHIDOptionsTypeSeizeDevice` (even though the events are still passed to the focused application)
- After becoming unresponsive, unplugging and replugging the device repeats the described behavior
- The program was run with root privileges

The relatively simple program can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/3783042

How can I modify it in order to not cause the card reader to become unresponsive after having sent the first event?

Comment: That is pretty much what I did for my MagTech reader. If you plug it in and swipe a card without a driver, does it type keys? Also, have you tried IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputValueCallback? That was what I used instead of IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback. It should work the way you have it.

Comment: @ThaneNorton yes, without driver everything works. I haven't tried with the callback on the device itself, but I begin to suspect that that's the device's fault (it was pretty cheap :D ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it was the device being defective. I ordered a new one and everything works now!